# Is there a performance difference between array and matrix operators?

Tags: matlab

I have several m files that are basically wrappers for very long, complicated equations of the sort that take more than one line in a journal article.  Currently, they use matrix operators, ie `*`,`/`,`^`.  I would like to convert them to array operators, ie `.*`,`./`,`.^` so that I can vectorize the calculations I do with them.

My question is, is there any reason I couldn't simply do a search and replace and change all of the operators?  Is there a performance issue with multiplying scalars with the element-wise operators?

Comment: If you just do a search and replace, how can you be sure that some of these equations aren't *already* operating on matrices?

Comment: Why don't you just do it and see if it gives you the desired result. If you're worried it will effect performance (which I highly doubt) then make a little test using either `tic` and `toc` or else `timeit`

Comment: If your objective is to vectorize the expressions, then provide a minimal working example that we can test to provide a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is not a matter of performance.

If you are dealing with **linear algebra** expressions, then you definitely do not want to simply search & replace: suppose `A = [1; 2; 3]` and `B = [4; 5; 6]` and you have `A'*B`, then you **cannot** convert to `A'.*B` because dimensions are not consistent with element-wise product (it will error).

In the case of **scalar multiplication**, I think the JIT is smart enough to consider `1*2` and `1.*2` equivalent and interpret them identically.

Comment: The last line was really what I was looking for (and couldn't find).  I wasn't sure if MATLAB treated the two operators differently with respect to scalars in terms of overhead.